# Powershell Workflow to reboot computers

Tags: powershell

Code:

```
workflow Test-RemoteReboot{
    param ([string[]]$serverNames)
    foreach -parallel($server in $serverNames){
        Restart-Computer -PSComputerName $server -Wait -Force
    }
}

Test-RemoteReboot SP,SP2
```

Issue:
this is a small excerpt from a pretty long workflow I built in powershell. By all accounts, this should work but I get the following error (even when running this script in isolation):

> Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The computer SP2 is 
>   skipped. Fail to retrieve its LastBootUpTime via the WMI service with the following error message: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA).
>   At line:433 char:25
>   + ...             Receive-Job -Job $job -Wait -Verbose -Debug -ErrorAction  ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], ActionPreferenceStopException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : [localhost]

I looked into the RPC server unavailable issue. Firewall is down, RPC Service is running, Servers are on domain, Workflow running from domain member computer, as domain admin. I can successfully PSRemote into the machines and do whatever. I can even do this:

```
workflow Test-LocalRebootRemotely{
param ([string[]]$serverNames)
    foreach -parallel($server in $serverNames){
        InlineScript { Restart-Computer -Force } -PSComputerName $server
    }
}

Test-LocalRebootRemotely SP,SP2
```

The problem is, is that I need a return value to determine if I need to reboot and handle other logic outside of the remote computer. I do notice that there is an abnormal pause just before it errors. So maybe it is a timeout? anyone have a similar issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the `Restart-Computer` cmdlet with the `-Protocol WSMan` parameter instead of the default DCOM over RPC protocol (`-Protocol DCOM`).

This would confirm that your RPC network packets are blocked somewhere.

Comment: The default [help page for Restart-Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-computer?view=powershell-7) shows version 7 which do not have this property any more. You have to look at [version 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-computer?view=powershell-5.1) for it.

Comment: @Stoinov Yes PowerShell 7 doesn't use DCOM anymore. Thus, if it's a firewall issue, you can't run any remote cmdlet.